# Prove the following from $L = \int_0^1 x^2 \sin^ {-1 }(\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}}) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

> Prove that $$L=\int_0^1 x^2 \sin^
> {-1
> }\left(\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right) \,dx= \frac{1}{3 \sqrt2} \left(\sqrt2\sin^
> {-1
> }(\tan{\frac{π}{8}})+\frac12 \log_e\frac{(1+\sqrt{\sqrt 2-1})}{(1-\sqrt{\sqrt 2-1)}}-\sqrt{\sqrt 2+1}\right)$$

I started by substituting $x = \tan(y)$ after which I spent quite some time and figured out; $$L_1=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\frac{π}{4} x^2 \sin^
{-1
}(\tan\frac{y}{2}) \ d(\tan y)^\frac{3}{2}$$

after which I chose integration by parts as the approach and finally ended on;

$$ L_2= \int_0^\frac{π}{4} \frac{2\tan\frac{y}{2}}{(1-\tan^2\frac{y}{2}) \sqrt{1-\tan^2\frac{y}{2}}} \ d(\tan\frac{y}{2})$$

I am stuck on the step mentioned above, I am unable to think of a substitution that can work here. It would be really great to see any alternate or a faster appproach to proving the above relation.

Edit -- To get $L_1$, after substitution i converted to siny and cosy and simplified it, To get $L_2$,  i used $\sin^
{-1
}(\tan\frac{y}{2})$ as 'U' and $d(tan y)^\frac{3}{2}$ as the 'V'  $\sin^
{-1
}(\tan\frac{y}{2})$ in the integration by parts (UV) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to check the road for the computation, had to correct some many places to go through. Here is what can be said along the lines from the question, following them as close as possible. I am using the following two substitutions:
$$
x^2 =\tan u\ ,\qquad t=\tan \frac u2\ .
$$
Note that $\tan \frac \pi8$ is equal to $\sqrt 2-1$, to *check* it use the formula for the tangent of the double angle, then compute $2a/(1-a^2)=1$. (To *get* it, solve the corresponding equation...)
So let us display this, using the following notation:
$$
a:=\tan\frac\pi 8=\sqrt 2-1\ .
$$
Denote by $J$ the integral to be computed. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=
\int_0^1x^2\arcsin\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\tan u\cdot 
\arcsin\frac {\tan u}{1+\frac 1{\cos u}}
\cdot\frac 1{2\sqrt{\tan u}}\cdot \frac 1{\cos^2 u}\; du
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\qquad\text{Under the $\arcsin$ there is $\sin u/(1+\cos u)$,
and using the relations}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{$\sin u=\sin \left(2\cdot \frac u2\right)=2\sin \frac u2\cos\frac u2$ and
$\cos u=\cos \left(2\cdot \frac u2\right)=2\cos^2 \frac u2-1$ }
\\[2mm]
&=\frac 13\int_0^{\pi/4}\arcsin\tan\frac u2\cdot\left(\ \tan ^{3/2}u\ \right)'\; du\qquad\text{ and using partial integration}
\\
&=\frac 13\left[\arcsin\tan\frac u2\cdot\tan ^{3/2}u\right]_0^{\pi/4}
-
\frac 13\int_0^{\pi/4}\arcsin'\tan\frac u2\cdot\tan'\frac u2\cdot\frac 12\ \cdot\ \tan ^{3/2}u\ \; du
\\
&=\frac 13\arcsin a
-
\frac 13\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac1{\sqrt{1-\tan^2\frac u2}}\cdot\frac 1{\cos^2\frac u2}\cdot\frac 12\ \cdot\ \tan ^{3/2}u\ \; du
\\
&=\frac 13\arcsin a
-
\frac 13\int_0^a\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\cdot(1+t^2)\cdot\frac 12\ \cdot\ \left(\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\right) ^{3/2}\ \; \frac{2\;dt}{1+t^2}
\\
&=\frac 13\arcsin a
-
\frac {2^{3/2}}3\int_0^a\frac{t^{3/2}}{(1-t^2)^2}\; dt
\\
&=\frac 13\arcsin a
-
\frac {2^{3/2}}3\left[
\frac 12\cdot\frac {\sqrt t}{1-t^2} 
- \frac 14\arctan\sqrt t 
- \frac 18\log\frac {1+\sqrt t}{1-\sqrt t}
\right]_0^a
\\
&=
\frac 13\arcsin a
-
\frac {2^{3/2}}3
\left(
\frac 12\cdot\frac {\sqrt a}{1-a^2} 
- \frac 14\arctan\sqrt a 
- \frac 18\log\frac {1+\sqrt a}{1-\sqrt a}
\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last form is a corrected version of the claimed result. In the last expression, some simplifications can still be done (although we already have a closed form). The term $\frac 13\arcsin a$ is also present in the question. The one in $\log \log\frac {1+\sqrt a}{1-\sqrt a}$ (where we can amplify by $(1+\sqrt a)$...) -  also appears. I am missing the $\arctan$-term. In the remained term, we can use $1-a^2=2a$ to get instead $\frac{\sqrt a}{1-a^2}=\frac{\sqrt a}{2a}=\frac1{2\sqrt a}$, and $1/\sqrt a$ leads to that $\sqrt{\sqrt 2+1}$ part.

---

Computer check (numerical check) in `pari/gp`:

```
? \p 100
? J = intnum(x=0, 1, x^2 * asin(x^2 / (1 + sqrt(1+x^4))))
%6 = 0.09106372975680152554935812253667127832325472076636050029484819808831519864812650201023012013520711399
? a = sqrt(2) - 1;
? asin(a)/3 - 2^(3/2)/3 * ( 1/4/sqrt(a) - atan(sqrt(a))/4 - 1/8 * log( (1+sqrt(a))/(1-sqrt(a)) ) )
%8 = 0.09106372975680152554935812253667127832325472076636050029484819808831519864812650201023012013520711399
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer only addresses a partial evaluation of the integral,

$$L = \int_0^1 x^2 \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right) \, dx$$

Substitute

$$y=\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}} \implies x=\sqrt{\frac{2y}{1-y^2}} \implies dx = \frac{1+y^2}{\sqrt{2y}\left(1-y^2\right)^{3/2}} \, dy$$

$$L = \int_0^{\sqrt2-1} \frac{2y}{1-y^2} \sin^{-1}(y) \, \frac{1+y^2}{\sqrt{2y}\left(1-y^2\right)^{3/2}} \, dy \\ = \sqrt2 \int_0^{\sqrt2-1} \frac{\sqrt y\left(1+y^2\right)}{\left(1-y^2\right)^{5/2}} \sin^{-1}(y) \, dy$$

Integrate by parts.

$$L = \frac{2\sqrt2}3 \left[\sin^{-1}(y) \left(\frac y{1-y^2}\right)^{3/2} \bigg|_{y=\sqrt2-1} - \int_0^{\sqrt2-1} \frac{y^{3/2}}{\left(1-y^2\right)^2} \, dy\right]$$

The remaining integral is elementary. Note that [$\sqrt2-1=\tan\frac\pi8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio).